# Why was Cuba not colonized by European empires other than Spain?

Tags: europe, colonization, americas, cuba, latin-america

I confused about the following links.

1. According to [Tordesillas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas) and the Protestant Reformation, what part of the world did Cuba belong to during that time?
2. What was the status of other European countries like Malta, Portugal, and Belgium during that time which prevented them from colonizing Cuba? There was the [Dutch revolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eighty_Years%27_War), the [Huguenot rebellions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huguenot_rebellions), the [English Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Civil_War), and the [Thirty Years' War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty_Years%27_War)

Comment: Was France unified yet (ie by that time partly still divided in dukedoms or post the 100 years war partly controlled by the english crown.)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Please do not edit other people's posts. That is considered bad etiquette.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya [Editing other people posts](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/editing#:~:text=If%20you%20are%20not%20comfortable%20with%20the%20idea%20of%20your%20contributions%20being%20collaboratively%20edited%20by%20other%20trusted%20users%2C%20this%20may%20not%20be%20the%20site%20for%20you.) is normal behavior on this site. Especially if a post has been closed, constructive edits are the main way these posts get reconsidered for opening. Have you taken our [tour] and looked over the [help]?

Comment: OK, I'll just vote to delete this answer rather than try to help you. Is that what you would prefer?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That is not what I would prefer. I would prefer to be helped. But I will only accept edits that I am satisfied with. Also, you cannot make edits which invalidate existing answers.

Comment: When you can explain how the Order of Malta was going to colonize the New World, I'll have time for you.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I do not care whether any of the listed countries were going to colonize the new world or not? Those are my three favorite European countries, and I am just listing them as examples for a hypothetical scenario.

Comment: I chose the feature "Edit and Re Open" in an attempt to help get your question re opened.  My further comments were aimed at attempting to get you to edit your answer so that it could get re opened, but I guess I assumed that you had taken @justCal's comment to heart.  Comments aren't somewhere for a debate.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because:

- According to the [Treaty of Tordesillas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Tordesillas), Cuba belonged to the Castilian half of the world.
- Malta, that is, the [Order of Malta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knights_Hospitaller), was [busy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Matapan) fighting the Ottomans until the 18th century.
- Belgium did not really exist until the [1830s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgian_Revolution). By then, the [Monroe Doctrine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monroe_Doctrine) was in place.

Answer (score 2):

Cuba (and the other countries that broke away from Spain and Mexico) was not colonizable by other European powers after Spain because of the United State's "Monroe Doctrine", whereby countries that tried to set up new colonies in the New World would be held in low regard by the United States.

Cuba didn't have anything exclusive enough to worth jeopardizing the relationship with the US or Spain. One could shop around the Caribbean for sugar.

In 1898 Spain was driven out of the New World and the United States set up a protectorate (formal and informal) over Cuba that lasted until 1959.

Comment: It  could be argued that if the split in Europe hadn't happened we could have had a big scrap in the Atlantic between US Navy and Royal Navy.   Congress basically said that : anyone who tries to retrieve return on their investments in enterprises in South America SHALL SPEAK with US first.